# Как задать обрамление для checkbox

Tags: css3, html, css

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать при помощи стилей (CSS) вокруг `checkbox` что-то вроде тени или обрамления? Желательно без применения картинок, заменяющих `checkbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
background-image: url(boxwithshadow.jpg);
```

2)

```
border-style:inset;/*outset, или groove, или ridge*/
border-width:5px;
border-color: #f00;
border-radius: 3px; /*только в CSS3!!!*/
```

Comment: Вот попробовал по второму способу:  

    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .checkbox{
      border-style:inset;
     border-width:50px;
     border-color: green;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input  type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" >
    </body>
    </html>

Не сработало. Только в Opera.

Comment: В файрфоксе и не получится. Там надо извращаться с кнопкой. =/

Comment: Плин, что-ж делать? Остается только при помощи картинки?

Comment: <button type='button'></button> - вот так. Тип кнопка указывать обязательно, так как он по умолчанию - "submit"  в некоторых браузерах.
Воть. Картинка - тоже выход.

Comment: С кнопкой прикольно получилось. Вот только не выделяется чекбокс. Видно, наилучший способ - картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

читануть можно здесь - [Стильные чекбоксы не для всех](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/stilnye-chekboksy-ne-dlya-vsekh)

а это [стильные чекбоксы с помощью CSS и jQuery](http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/56)